# Change image after click on image in javascript(Not using dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

Right now i am changing the image by dropdown selection. But i want to change image by click on choice of image Like.
[image]

If the user click on green t-shirt image then set green image in `<div>`, If user click on yellow t-shirt then set yellow t-shirt in `<div>.`
But right now i am using dropdown for this procedure.

```js
var bgArray = [
  'https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg',
  'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020715_be_my_valentine_chocolate_box_205.jpeg'
]
$('#imageroom').on('change', function() {
  value = $(this).val() - 1;
  $('#backgroundIMage').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + bgArray[value] + ')'
  });
});
```

```css
#backgroundIMage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Change image</label>
<select size="1" id="imageroom">
  <option value="1">Image 1</option>
  <option value="2">IMage 2</option>
</select>


<!-- for demo only -->
<hr>
<div id="backgroundIMage"></div>
```

Comment: Note that switching to functionality based on image clicks might not meet accessibility standards: how do users who can't use a mouse or other pointing device select an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the `click` event on an image. In the example below, I loop through the `bgArray` and dynamically display all the images in that array.

When one of the images is clicked, I show that image in the `backgroundIMage` element. Notice that I am using [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to make sure the image click works for any images that are dynamically added to the `picker`.

```js
var bgArray = [
  'https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg',
  'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020715_be_my_valentine_chocolate_box_205.jpeg'
];

$("#picker").on("click", "img", function() {
  //use event delegation to handle click event of any img tags in #picker
  $('#backgroundIMage').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + this.src + ')'
  });
  
  //toggle selected
  $("#picker img").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$(function() {
  //initialize the picker on document load
  bgArray.forEach(function(src) {
    var img = new Image(50, 50);
    img.src = src;
    $("#picker").append(img);
  });
  
  //default the first one to be selected
  $("#picker img").first().trigger("click");
});
```

```css
#backgroundIMage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#picker img {
  padding: 5px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Change image
<div id="picker"></div>

<hr>
<div id="backgroundIMage"></div>
```

Comment: If my question is good. then voting up this question help to others. thanks dave.

Comment: Can you check my next step. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739243/after-one-click-set-two-different-image-in-two-div-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Although it is king of hard to know *exactly* what you are trying to do, you should try to work with the `click` event of the image.

For a specific image :

```
$('#myImageId').click(function(){ 
  $(this).css//etc..
});
```

For all images :

```
$('img').click(function(){
   $(this).css//etc..  
});
```