# After one click set two different image in two div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am implementing customize t-shirt using java script. Right now i am set one background image after click on image choice. But right now i want to set two different image in two div after click once.
[image]

If user click on yellow t-shirt then set tow images in two different div.(front size image and backside image of t-shirt).

```js
var bgArray = [
  'https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg',
  'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020715_be_my_valentine_chocolate_box_205.jpeg',
   'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0016630_quad_diamond_earings_205.jpeg',
];

$(".picker-image").on("click", "img", function() {
  $('.backgroundIMage').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + this.src + ')'
  });
});

$(function() {
  bgArray.forEach(function(src) {
    var img = new Image(50, 50);
    img.src = src;
    $(".picker-image").append(img);
  });
});
```

```css
.backgroundIMage{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    outline:1px dotted gray;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
  <div class="picker-image"></div>



<!-- for demo only -->
<hr>
<div class="backgroundIMage"></div>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid #333">
Front Side Image
</div>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid #333">
back Side Image
</div>
```

Finally i want click t-shirt then two images set into two div front side of image and back side of image.

For Hints
https://jsfiddle.net/varunPes/p9L76j0z/2/

Comment: How do you know which is the front and which is the back?

Comment: I think should add two images front side and backside. If user click on yellow t-shirt then should be get two image.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: open this link http://www.99tshirts.com/p/58932/bruce_lee_fan_tshirt and click on (customize this design) button. Then may be clear.

Comment: But it's not clear here. That link will rot in the future. A question on StackOverflow should identify a problem and expected results. Neither is included here

Comment: @charlietfl. Basically i want to set two different image two div after click on image.

Comment: OK. i will update my question for more clearificatoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the relationship between the front and back images. I'd suggest using an array of objects, where each item in the array contains the front and back images. Then when the selector item is clicked, you can populate the front and back images.

```js
var bgArray = [
  {
    front: 'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020715_be_my_valentine_chocolate_box_205.jpeg',
    back: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1/'
  },
  {
    front: 'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0016630_quad_diamond_earings_205.jpeg',
    back: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2/'
  },
  {
    front: 'https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg',
    back: 'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3/'
  }
];

$(".picker-image").on("click", "img", function() {
  //find the item in the array where the 'front' matches the URL of the image that was clicked
  var src = this.src;
  var item = bgArray.find(function(element) {
    return element.front === src;
  });
  
  //set the front image
  $("#front").css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + item.front + ')'
  });

  //set the back image
  $("#back").css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + item.back + ')'
  });
  
  //indicate the selected one
  $(".picker-image img").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  
});

$(function() {
  //dynamically populate image picker
  bgArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var img = new Image(50, 50);
    img.src = item.front;
    $(".picker-image").append(img);
  });

  //select the first one by default
  $(".picker-image img").first().trigger("click");
});
```

```css
.product {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid #333;
  margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.picker-image img {
  padding: 5px;  
}

.selected {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Pick One
<div class="picker-image"></div>

<hr>
<div id="front" class="product">
  Front Side Image
</div>
<div id="back" class="product">
  Back Side Image
</div>
```

Comment: i just added one fiddle for hints. please check.

Comment: I want when user click on one t-shirt image then two image append into two div. And that two image is back side and front side image.

Comment: Can you do one think? If click on front image then auto click same back image.If it is possible then it is use full for me.

Comment: thanks a lot.  Sorry for miss communication. then voting up help to others. again thanks. It is  very use full for me.

Comment: I have one doubt. When i put image link from my project. then it is showing. TypeError: item is undefined:   

'background-image': 'url(' + item.front + ')'

Comment: This happens if the image that was clicked can't be found in the `bgArray` front items. I can't debug it further without seeing a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

for this you have to make one default JSON structure like below:

```
{
 data:[
  {
   "mainSrc":"https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg",
   "backSrc":"sss.jpg",
   "frontSrc":"sddsd.jpg"
  },
{
   "mainSrc":"https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg",
   "backSrc":"sss.jpg",
   "frontSrc":"sddsd.jpg"
  }
 ]
}
```

and then refer the index dynamically from click element attr and the get front back src append it.

Comment: can you explain me more or create demo

Comment: hi, please have look on link whether the think is expected:
http://embed.plnkr.co/gMasUeCud36JEpsGTv5P/

if it is useful make this as useful please vote me..

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this fiddle below :

Fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x5odxyz/5/)

Just add id for front and back image div in html code and assign image background through javascript. Here is the changed code.

```
var bgArray = [
  'https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.13.0/img/new-city-home/bang-img/softtoys3.jpg',
  'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020715_be_my_valentine_chocolate_box_205.jpeg',
  'https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0016630_quad_diamond_earings_205.jpeg',
];

$(".picker-image").on("click", "img", function() {
  $('.backgroundIMage').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + this.src + ')'
  });
  $('#front').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + bgArray[1] + ')'
 });
 $('#back').css({
   'background-image': 'url(' + bgArray[2] + ')'
 });
});

<div style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid #333" id="front">
  Front Side Image
</div>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px;border:1px solid #333" id="back">
  back Side Image
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't make people play *"spot the difference"* in your code vs OP code. A code only answer with no explanation of what was changed is of little to no value to anyone